# Trusting types of functions with boring arguments

Tags: haskell, ghc, coercion

As a general rule, Haskell types can only be trusted if they don't contain any functions, because Haskell allows runtime errors and non-termination, and even then only when they are fully forced. So in general, if I have a function `f :: X -> Y`, and I have `x :: X`, I can only be confident of `Y` if I force `f x`. In a recent question/answer, I explored a situation where the `X` type is "boring": specifically, I was working with `Data.Type.Coercion.Coercion`:

```
data Coercion a b where
  Coercion :: Coercible a b => Coercion a b
```

While the `Coercible a b` constraint means that `Coercion` is not quite a nullary data constructor, the coercion system ensures that a `Coercible a b` dictionary is always represented by `\x -> x`, so it almost might as well be nullary.

My impression, which I'd love someone to verify or refute, is that when a function's arguments are *all* boring in this sort of sense, then applying the function just once, with a single set of type arguments, and forcing the result, allows its type to be trusted for all type arguments. For instance, given Edward Kmett's

```
class Representational t where
  rep :: Coercion a b -> Coercion (t a) (t b)
```

I am hoping this works:

```
type family A :: k
type family B :: k
coerceAB :: Coercion A B
coerceAB = unsafeCoerce (Coercion :: Coercion () ())

reallyRepresentational :: forall t . Representational t => Proxy t
reallyRepresentational = (rep coerceAB :: Coercion (t A) (t B)) `seq` Proxy
```

I imagine that there's no way for an implementation of `rep` to fail on any non-bottom input if it manages to pass `reallyRepresentational`. Is this correct?

Comment: "Haskell types can only be trusted if they don't have arrows in them, because Haskell allows runtime errors and non-termination" <- what do you mean by this? _Every_ type is inhabited by `⊥`, not just function types, so none of them can be trusted.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, if you fully force something without functions, then you have a proper witness. For instance, once you force something of type `x :~: y`, you know that `x ~ y` (although "internally", that evidence is only available under a pattern match). If you force a function, that does *not* generally give you a witness in Haskell.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: IIUC, the last part tests "representational-ness" using two skolem constants `A,B` in order to guarantee it on all types. I wonder if this might suffer from the same problem as an early version of `Data.Constraint.Forall`, where using two skolem constants was not enough "thanks" to closed type families being able to count how many arguments are distinct.

Comment: @chi, I thought about that, but in this case the user doesn't get so much access, since `rep` gets only `Representational t` and the coercions I don't see anywhere to *put* leaked information. I could be missing something, of course.

Comment: In fact, I think I can probably get away with just using one "skolem", and its (exportable!) reflexive coercion. The only weird bit about it is that I want it to be polykinded.